# How to take elements from JSON from web service in C# console application to make exchange office?

Tags: c#, json

I am new at programming and I try to make exchange office in C# console application. I use free API service for current currency rates. On this way i can read all API elements, but i don't know how to take elements what i need? For example i need to take USDEUR rate. How to do that?

My code is

```
string url = @"http://apilayer.net/api/live? access_key=8efc5a54419e913b695f694bbef4d97f& currencies = EUR,GBP,CAD,PLN& source = USD& format = 1";
        string objects = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);

        var lista = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objects, Formatting.Indented);

        var finish = lista.ToArray();

        Console.WriteLine(finish);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to let *JSON* string be object.

There are two way you can make it

1. use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject method to get model.

Make a `model`

```
public class Quotes
{
    public double USDAED { get; set; }
    public double USDAFN { get; set; }
    public double USDALL { get; set; }
    public double USDAMD { get; set; }
    public double USDANG { get; set; }
    public double USDAOA { get; set; }
    public double USDARS { get; set; }
    public double USDAUD { get; set; }
    public double USDAWG { get; set; }
    public double USDAZN { get; set; }
    public double USDBAM { get; set; }
    public int USDBBD { get; set; }
    public double USDBDT { get; set; }
    public double USDBGN { get; set; }
    public double USDBHD { get; set; }
    public double USDBIF { get; set; }
    public int USDBMD { get; set; }
    public double USDBND { get; set; }
    public double USDBOB { get; set; }
    public double USDBRL { get; set; }
    public int USDBSD { get; set; }
    public double USDBTC { get; set; }
    public double USDBTN { get; set; }
    public double USDBWP { get; set; }
    public double USDBYN { get; set; }
    public int USDBYR { get; set; }
    public double USDBZD { get; set; }
    public double USDCAD { get; set; }
    public double USDCDF { get; set; }
    public double USDCHF { get; set; }
    public double USDCLF { get; set; }
    public double USDCLP { get; set; }
    public double USDCNY { get; set; }
    public double USDCOP { get; set; }
    public double USDCRC { get; set; }
    public int USDCUC { get; set; }
    public double USDCUP { get; set; }
    public double USDCVE { get; set; }
    public double USDCZK { get; set; }
    public double USDDJF { get; set; }
    public double USDDKK { get; set; }
    public double USDDOP { get; set; }
    public double USDDZD { get; set; }
    public double USDEGP { get; set; }
    public double USDERN { get; set; }
    public double USDETB { get; set; }
    public double USDEUR { get; set; }
    public double USDFJD { get; set; }
    public double USDFKP { get; set; }
    public double USDGBP { get; set; }
    public double USDGEL { get; set; }
    public double USDGGP { get; set; }
    public double USDGHS { get; set; }
    public double USDGIP { get; set; }
    public double USDGMD { get; set; }
    public double USDGNF { get; set; }
    public double USDGTQ { get; set; }
    public double USDGYD { get; set; }
    public double USDHKD { get; set; }
    public double USDHNL { get; set; }
    public double USDHRK { get; set; }
    public double USDHTG { get; set; }
    public double USDHUF { get; set; }
    public int USDIDR { get; set; }
    public double USDILS { get; set; }
    public double USDIMP { get; set; }
    public double USDINR { get; set; }
    public int USDIQD { get; set; }
    public double USDIRR { get; set; }
    public double USDISK { get; set; }
    public double USDJEP { get; set; }
    public double USDJMD { get; set; }
    public double USDJOD { get; set; }
    public double USDJPY { get; set; }
    public double USDKES { get; set; }
    public double USDKGS { get; set; }
    public double USDKHR { get; set; }
    public double USDKMF { get; set; }
    public double USDKPW { get; set; }
    public double USDKRW { get; set; }
    public double USDKWD { get; set; }
    public double USDKYD { get; set; }
    public double USDKZT { get; set; }
    public double USDLAK { get; set; }
    public double USDLBP { get; set; }
    public double USDLKR { get; set; }
    public double USDLRD { get; set; }
    public double USDLSL { get; set; }
    public double USDLTL { get; set; }
    public double USDLVL { get; set; }
    public double USDLYD { get; set; }
    public double USDMAD { get; set; }
    public double USDMDL { get; set; }
    public double USDMGA { get; set; }
    public double USDMKD { get; set; }
    public double USDMMK { get; set; }
    public double USDMNT { get; set; }
    public double USDMOP { get; set; }
    public double USDMRO { get; set; }
    public double USDMUR { get; set; }
    public double USDMVR { get; set; }
    public double USDMWK { get; set; }
    public double USDMXN { get; set; }
    public double USDMYR { get; set; }
    public double USDMZN { get; set; }
    public double USDNAD { get; set; }
    public double USDNGN { get; set; }
    public double USDNIO { get; set; }
    public double USDNOK { get; set; }
    public double USDNPR { get; set; }
    public double USDNZD { get; set; }
    public double USDOMR { get; set; }
    public int USDPAB { get; set; }
    public double USDPEN { get; set; }
    public double USDPGK { get; set; }
    public double USDPHP { get; set; }
    public double USDPKR { get; set; }
    public double USDPLN { get; set; }
    public double USDPYG { get; set; }
    public double USDQAR { get; set; }
    public double USDRON { get; set; }
    public double USDRSD { get; set; }
    public double USDRUB { get; set; }
    public double USDRWF { get; set; }
    public double USDSAR { get; set; }
    public double USDSBD { get; set; }
    public double USDSCR { get; set; }
    public double USDSDG { get; set; }
    public double USDSEK { get; set; }
    public double USDSGD { get; set; }
    public double USDSHP { get; set; }
    public double USDSLL { get; set; }
    public double USDSOS { get; set; }
    public double USDSRD { get; set; }
    public double USDSTD { get; set; }
    public double USDSVC { get; set; }
    public double USDSYP { get; set; }
    public double USDSZL { get; set; }
    public double USDTHB { get; set; }
    public double USDTJS { get; set; }
    public double USDTMT { get; set; }
    public double USDTND { get; set; }
    public double USDTOP { get; set; }
    public double USDTRY { get; set; }
    public double USDTTD { get; set; }
    public double USDTWD { get; set; }
    public double USDTZS { get; set; }
    public double USDUAH { get; set; }
    public double USDUGX { get; set; }
    public int USDUSD { get; set; }
    public double USDUYU { get; set; }
    public double USDUZS { get; set; }
    public double USDVEF { get; set; }
    public int USDVND { get; set; }
    public double USDVUV { get; set; }
    public double USDWST { get; set; }
    public double USDXAF { get; set; }
    public double USDXAG { get; set; }
    public double USDXAU { get; set; }
    public double USDXCD { get; set; }
    public double USDXDR { get; set; }
    public double USDXOF { get; set; }
    public double USDXPF { get; set; }
    public double USDYER { get; set; }
    public double USDZAR { get; set; }
    public double USDZMK { get; set; }
    public double USDZMW { get; set; }
    public double USDZWL { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public string terms { get; set; }
    public string privacy { get; set; }
    public int timestamp { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public Quotes quotes { get; set; }
}
```

use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` method to get model.

```
var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonData);
var USDEUR = jsonObj.quotes.USDEUR //object property to get your field.
```

2. use `JObject.Parse` method to Parse json

sample code:

```
string url = @"http://apilayer.net/api/live? access_key=8efc5a54419e913b695f694bbef4d97f& currencies = EUR,GBP,CAD,PLN& source = USD& format = 1";
string objects = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
var jsonObj= JObject.Parse(objects);
string USDEUR = (string)jsonObj["quotes"]["USDEUR"];
```

[C# ONLINE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rBfPxN)

**Note:**

There are two way can create model easily.

1. You can use Web Essentials in Visual Studio, use Edit > Paste special > paste JSON as class, you can easier to know the relation between Json and model.
2. If you can't use Web Essentials you can instead http://json2csharp.com/ online JSON to Model class.

Comment: Keep in mind, that he could keep only the fields(variables) he needs for his app. Also, a simpliest answer to this is to use a [json to c# tool](https://jsonutils.com/), which is what u did to answer.